# Find folder path based on each character of a word and use grep on selected file

Tags: bash, shell, grep, sh

I want to run the code below and use grep to search for "LARGE_NAME" inside a file that is in a path that needs yet to be determined.
Important:

- Both file and folder names are just 1 distinct letter of the alphabet
  [a-z];
- Files have no file extension. Example: "$dir/$letter1/$letter2", $letter2 is the file;
- I know that I found the path if there is no more subfolders to be searched.

.

```
./query.sh LARGE_NAME
```

The final file could be in:

```
$dir/$letter1
$dir/$letter1/$letter2
$dir/$letter1/$letter2/$letter3/
.... so on
```

Where:

```
$letter1 = L
$letter2 = A
$letter3 = R
.... so on
```

I want to optimize my code that works but have too many nested IFs. Below is an example with just 3 letter search:

query.sh file:

```
#!/opt/homebrew/bin/bash
dir=$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )

letter1=$(echo ${1,,}|cut -b1)
if [ -f "$dir/$letter1" ]; then
    grep -ai "^$1" "$dir/$letter1"
else
    letter2=$(echo ${1,,}|cut -b2)
    if [ -f "$dir/$letter1/$letter2" ]; then
        grep -ai "^$1" "$dir/$letter1/$letter2"
    else
        letter3=$(echo ${1,,}|cut -b3)
        if [ -f "$dir/$letter1/$letter2/$letter3" ]; then
            grep -ai "^$1" "$dir/$letter1/$letter2/$letter3"
        fi
    fi
fi
```

How can I rewrite my code to search for up to 50 sub folders until it finds the last/final one with the file I want to grep?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So build the path cummulatively, one slash and letter at a time.

```
input=${1,,}
path="$dir"
for ((i = 0; i < ${#input}; ++i)); do
    letter=${input:i:1}
    path="$path/$letter"
    if [[ -f "$path" ]]; then
        grep -ai "^$1" "$path"
    fi
done
```

Comment: Hello @KamilCuk! Your answer is working! Thank you very much. I really appreciate it.
I think I didn't make it clear, but I don't need to search for all characters of the input word. The first time I find [[ -f "$path" ]] then it could be the last search. 
For example: if input = "LARGE_NAME" and I find [[ -f "$path" ]] after searching for ""LARG" (only 4 letters into your loop), then I could do the grep and finish. 
Could you help me improving your answer? Thanks again

Comment: https://phoenixnap.com/kb/bash-break